# rejected HTTP promise doesn't hit catch block

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I use VueJs (and Vuex) with Axios to communicate with an Express Api. I can delete my own user account consuming a service

```
import api from '@/services/api.js';

export default {
  deleteAccount: () => api().delete('/users')
};
```

where `api` is the `axios` instance. I don't need to pass in a user ID because the api identifies the user by the *token*.

Within my settings view I can consume this service

```
<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex';

import UserService from '@/services/users'; 

export default {
  name: 'Settings',
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('alert', [
      'showSuccessAlert',
      'showErrorAlert'
    ])
    deleteAccount: async function() {
      try {
        await UserService.deleteAccount();

        this.showSuccessAlert({ message: 'Account was deleted successfully' });
        // other stuff
      } catch (error) {
        this.showErrorAlert({ message: error.message });
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Calling `UserService.deleteAccount()` returns me a pending promise. Using `await` returns me the api response.

Currently the api always returns a `500` for testing purposes. I thought, that if the Promise gets rejected the code will always jump directly into the catch block. Here, the code returns a rejected Promise (and writes a "Internal Server Error" to the console but passes and shows a success alert / never executes the code from the catch block.

What is wrong with the code? Did I misunderstand promises?

---

**Update**

My axios instance

```
import axios from 'axios';

import TokensService from '@/services/tokens.js';
import store from '@/store/store.js';

function getTokenString() {
  return `Bearer ${TokensService.getToken()}`;
}

export default () => {
  const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: getTokenString(),
    },
  });

  instance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    config.headers.Authorization = getTokenString();
    return config;
  }, (err) => Promise.reject(err));

  instance.interceptors.response.use((res) => res, (err) => {
    if (err.response.status === 401) {
      store.dispatch('authentication/destroySession');
      store.dispatch('alert/showErrorAlert', { message: err.message });
    }

    return err;
  });

  return instance;
};
```

Calling `api().delete()` is the same as `axios.delete('http://localhost:3000/users')`

Comment: `returns a 500` - http status does not necessarily mean a rejected promise - the browsers `fetch` for instance does not reject on a 500, or 404, or any successful (as far as getting a http response) request

Comment: Does returning status code 500 automatically reject the promise?

Comment: yes, normally it does

Comment: what does the code for `api().delete` look like? is it your code?

Comment: as far as I know all "failed requests" will jump into the catch block

Comment: as far as you know ... clearly it doesn't :p again, is `api().delete` *your* code? if not, what is it

Comment: status 500 is not a failed request, it's a server error. It's a request that succeeded with a status code indicating the logic on the server behind the request failed. As far as the browser is concerned, the request itself still succeeded, so it won't trigger automatic rejection. Eg the fetch() API Jaro mentions.

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, it is my code, I will update my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try returning a rejected promise here

```
  instance.interceptors.response.use((res) => res, (err) => {
    if (err.response.status === 401) {
      store.dispatch('authentication/destroySession');
      store.dispatch('alert/showErrorAlert', { message: err.message });
    }

    return Promise.reject(err);
  });
```

as per examples https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors

Comment: oh yes, I had to change `return err;` to `return Promise.reject(err);`